# openshift & optaplanner rostering

Tags: optaplanner, rostering, optaweb-employee-rostering

I have been following instructions at https://github.com/kiegroup/optashift-employee-rostering (readme). I was able to deploy roster app in openshift and dont see any errors in log. I have also created external route (localhost).

but when i access roster application as http://localhost/roster I get  error "Not Found".  But i see pod running and service active.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the "route" path from "/roster" to "/"

Now I can access roster application using http://localhost/gwtui/gwtui.html